# VM says "Requires Ops Agent" after installing ops agent

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an issue with one of my VMs and I need to see if it's running out of memory. When I clicked on the overview tab to look at the memory utilization, I saw "Requires Ops Agent".

[image]

I clicked the "Install" button to install the ops agent on the VM, which basically involved running some pre-generated commands in the cloud shell. I saw in the terminal that the installation succeeded:

```
SUCCEEDED: [1/1] (100.0%)
FAILED: [0/1] (0.0%)
COMPLETED: [1/1] (100.0%)
```

I then clicked on the VM again to check the overview and I still see the same error: "Requires Ops Agent".

Thanks, Google!

Comment: Reboot the virtual machine. Then check the logs to see if Ops Agent is starting or failing.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting 1 hour solved it. Eventually the VM's metrics started showing up.